# Mapping a Axios response to typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am trying to map a Json response to a Typescript model. I tried to generate the typescript models, and although they did generate, they're sadly not working correctly. Therefore, I am exploring creating my own models in hopes to find out my the generated gRPC Typescript models did not work.

I will note using the axios response works fine. Example

```
        })}`).then(res => {
            return res.data
        })
```

then in the calling component

```
const posts = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await api.getAllTodos()
            if (response != null) {
                todoArr.value =  response.todo
            }
        return response

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error while getting the response in home posts:', error)
    }
}
```

However, I want to return a Typescript object because the above `posts` method causes linting issues. I would prefer to access them directly with getter and setters.

Full example of axios call:

```
const grpcClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: url.baseUrl,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
});

async getAllTodos() {
        try {
            return await grpcClient.get<ITodoAllResponse>(`/v1/getAll?${qs.stringify({
            })}`).then(res => {
                const { data } = res
                console.log("res in getAll", data)
                return data
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("error" + err);
        }
    },
```

[image]
interface

```
export interface ITodoAllResponse {
    todos: Array<Todo>;

}
```

How can I map my axios response to a Typescript model?

---- update 1 ----

I updated my models

```
export interface ITodo {
    id: string;
    title: string;
}
```

---

```
import { ITodo } from "./Todo";

export interface ITodoAllResponse {
    todos: ITodo[];
}
```

error in console

```
Error while getting the response in home posts: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')
```

however `data.todo.title` does exist.

```
res in getAll {todo: Array(5)} todo: Array(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like in your response data image it's `todo: Todo[]` and you have `todos: Todo[]` in your interface